# How can i check if two SKSpriteNodes are near each other?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit

How can i check if two SKSpriteNodes are near each other? like in a radius of 100. i am using the gamescene.swift and gamescene.sks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SKSpriteNode has a position property with the (x, y).

Distance between two positions is `sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)`

So:

```
let dist = sqrt(pow(sk1.position.x - sk2.position.x, 2.0) + pow(sk1.position.y - sk2.position.y, 2.0))
if dist < 100 {
    // they are close
}
```

This is center to center.

Based on @MartinR's comment, you could also

```
let dist = hypot(sk1.position.x - sk2.position.x, sk1.position.y - sk2.position.y)
```

Which does the distance function for you.

Comment: There is also a handy `hypot` function :)

Comment: Give the sprite a big physicsBody and use contact detection?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use built in SKPhysicsBody,  then just set the body to a circle with radius of 100,  then you can use the didBeginContact method when a contact occurs:

```
func setup()
{
    let physicsBody1 = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:100.0)
    physicsBody1.categoryBitMask = 1
    physicsBody1.collisionBitMask = 0
    physicsBody1.contactTestBitMask = 2
    sprite1.physicsBody = physicsBody1


    let physicsBody2 = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:100.0)
    physicsBody2.categoryBitMask = 2
    physicsBody2.collisionBitMask = 0
    physicsBody2.contactTestBitMask = 1
    sprite2.physicsBody = physicsBody2
}


func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact)
{
  //find some tutorials to your liking, and do your contact code here
}
```